# When I select SDK 30 in sketchware, Ads not showing

Tags: ads, sketchware

i am using sketchware pro6. 3.0 Fix1 app. When I use SDK 29 Ads properly showing in my app. But when i change SDK to 30 Ads not showing & I am geting error when I open my app.  Error is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks;
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdsy.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass@@19.7.0:4)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzf.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:11)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgb.zzaey(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbgg.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:6)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcml.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:8)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdaw.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:7)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqk.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:17)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfm.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:8)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqw.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:15)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqj.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:9)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:6)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcps.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:7)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqk.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:17)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbwk.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:7)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeqc.get(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhp.zzagj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:235)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdje.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:71)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:26)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:13)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:123)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:15)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:20)
at com.RadhaKrishnaHDWallpaper.MainActivity.initializeLogic(MainActivity.java:266)
at com.RadhaKrishnaHDWallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3404)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7661)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:594)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks
... 43 more

Please anyone know how to fix that issue then please reply

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this? Do you remember how?

Comment: No, I switch to  Android studio now